# Enum print question in Java

Tags: java

I declared an `enum` `Card` which has a `getValue` method that returns an `int` representation with for every `Card` (clubs, hearts, etc.). I observed that I am unable to use the `+` operator in the following statement because the compiler thinks I am performing an add operation with two incompatible types.

Why doesn't the compiler automatically overload here? The only way I can display this is if I stuff a `""` in between so `currentCard + "" + currentCard.getValue()` is accepted. Is there anyway to get around this?

```
for(Card currentCard: Card.values())  
    System.out.println(currentCard+ currentCard.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is simply that the plus operator only does String concatenation when there is a String as one of the items being added together.  There is nothing that makes it assume String just because it's inside a println.

That's why once you throw an empty string in there, it then sees this as String concatenation and concatenates the string representation of each item together.  Otherwise you are adding an object of type Card to an int.

So solve it, simply do this:

```
System.out.println(currentCard.toString() + currentCard.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to convince the java compiler you are working with strings, there's no way the compiler can figure that out automatically when looking at an enum and an int.  personally, i would use:

```
"" + currentCard + currentCard.getValue()
```

Comment: I think using toString() is clearer than putting a "" + in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `toString()`, as suggested in the `Card` example seen [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html). Then all you need is this:

```
 System.out.println(currentCard);
```